# Gmusicbrowser does not let me bind Fn key

Tags: bind, keys, gmusicbrowser

Im trying to bind the play/pause button to Fn+Down but it only lets me put down

Comment: The Fn key isn't handled by the OS, but by the keyboard itself

Answer (score 0):

[gmusicbrowser FAQ:](http://gmusicbrowser.org/faq.html) How do I control gmusicbrowser with global shortcuts or multimedia keys ?

You have to configure your window manager to execute the command `gmusicbrowser -cmd PlayPause` when the key combination you want is pressed. Replace "PlayPause" by the command you want, to see the list of available commands, run `gmusicbrowser -listcmd`.

If you have the DBus perl bindings, you can also control gmusicbrowser though the [DBus interface](http://wiki.gmusicbrowser.org/doku.php?id=dbus_api).

If you use Gnome > 2.18, you can use the included gnome multimedia keys plugin (needs DBus perl bindings), that will automatically make the Play/Pause, Stop, Previous and Next multimedia keys work.

---

- Also this: [Getting Media Keys to work with Gmusicbrowser?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1907527)
- and this:  [gmusicbrowser ignores keyboard shortcuts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gmusicbrowser/+bug/1051966) might be helpful.

Comment: For some reason running that command just opened a song

Comment: @opened a song: `gmusicbrowser -cmd PlayPause` is supposed to do exactly that! Please read again, especially the `DBus interface` part!